# How best to find and remove an element from a multidimensional array in coldfusion

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, coldfusion

I'm trying to remove an element (the full array when position 1 matches my search string) from a multidimensional array in coldfusion based on a search string. I came up with the following, which works (the second element in the array here is deleted), BUT it errors out because it messes up the indexing - it tries to check for an nth element when the array is of length n-1 after the delete.

```
<cfset Profiles  =
[ 
    ["aaa",     "xdg",   "123",   "xyz",  "ggg"   ],
    ["bbb",     "xwa",   "234",   "xyz",  "fff"   ],
    ["ccc",     "xed",   "567",   "xyz",  "eee"   ],
    ["ddd",     "xae",   "789",   "xyz",  "hhh"   ],
    ["eee",     "xsr",   "901",   "xyz",  "bbb"   ],
    ["fff",     "xdg",   "902",   "xyz",  "jjj"   ]
]/>
```

```
<cfset CheckFor = "bbb" />
<cfset Position = 1 /> 
<cfloop array="#Profiles#" index="arrayIndex"   >

    ArrayFind: #arrayFind( arrayIndex, CheckFor  )#<br />

    <cfif #arrayFind( arrayIndex, CheckFor  )# eq 1 > 
        #arrayDeleteAt( Profiles, Position )#
    </cfif>

    <cfset Position++ /> 

</cfloop>

<cfdump var="#DocumentProfiles#" />
```

Comment: you can probably use `cfbreak` after the delete to exit the loop. OR if you wish to delete more than one, you can store indexes in temporary array to delete and delete after the loop.

Comment: That's a good answer.  You should post it as such.

Comment: @tech2017 I do need to delete more than one, I like that solution.

Comment: What version of ColdFusion?

Comment: Have you considered using an ounce of prevention when building your array instead of a pound of cure afterwards?

Comment: Loop backwards through the array.

Comment: @SteveBryant So overt, it's covert!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this:

```
  <cfif #arrayFind( arrayIndex, CheckFor  )# eq 1 > 
        #arrayDeleteAt( Profiles, Position )#
    </cfif>

    <cfset Position++ />
```

to this:

```
<cfif #arrayFind( arrayIndex, CheckFor  )# eq 1 > 
        #arrayDeleteAt( Profiles, Position )#
<cfelse>
    <cfset Position++ /> 
</cfif>
```

Comment: Can this be done without the loop at all? I.E. Check the entire array for the string and delete the row if it appears?

Comment: Don't forget to ditch the extra #s around the arrafind(). And you can als get rid of the "eq 1" since the cfif will evaluate the boolean output of the arrayfind() anyway.

Comment: @PatrickSchomburg No performance change. Just not needed in that case. Prettier code makes for a happier future you or whoever has to edit it later. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you are ACF10+, instead of an explicit loop, you can do this:

```
<cfscript>

Profiles = [
    ["aaa","bbb","asdf"]
  , ["bbb","asdf","asdfasfs"]
  , ["ccc","dfhgasdfg","bbb"]
  , ["bbb","asdfasdf","Aasdfa"]
] ;

checkfor = "bbb" ;

//// FROM HERE ////    
arrayEach(
  Profiles,
  function(obj){
    obj[1]==checkfor?arrayDelete(Profiles,obj):'';
  }
);
//// TO HERE ////

WriteDump(Profiles);

</cfscript>
```

EDIT: Or even better, no loop. Still ACF10+ but also works in Lucee.

```
p2 = arrayFilter( Profiles, function(obj){ return obj[1] != checkfor ; } );
```

Comment: The two functions, arrayEach and arrayFilter, return slightly different things. When I added a capitalized element to the Profiles array, arrayFilter removed the capitalized row while arrayEach left it in the output array. Between the two, ==/EQ (my arrayEach) seems to be exhibiting sort-of-"case-sensitive" behavior, while !=/NEQ (my arrayFilter) is exhibiting sort-of-"case-insensitive" behavior. I'll look at the difference between the two. I'm missing something. :-/